# How to modify the pipeline name in gitlab. I am getting the Merge request title as the pipeline title

Tags: gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Hi anyone has any idea how to set the variable name in gitlab pipeline.
I am having an issue where the job title name is always shown as the merge request title.

[image: Image having all the job title name as the merge request title]

I already tried finding apis to modify the title of job but to no luck.
I did find GET api/v4/projects/ of gitlab but I find something weird here as well. The title and message is not the commit message but the same MR title.

[image]

Can anyone help. Thanks in advance

[EDIT]

1. The commits have different messsage
2. The pipeline is not being run on the same commit as shown from SHA of the pipeline
3. The issue is basically always the MR title is being used as pipeline name

Answer (score 0):

Pipeline objects don't have a "Title" attribute. What you're seeing on that page is the commit message/title. GitLab displays that so it's easy to differentiate them on the page.

These pseudo-titles will be the same in these two scenarios:

1. You're running multiple pipelines on the same commit, for example triggers, schedules, etc. that run against the latest commit in a branch. If there aren't new commits between these pipelines, they will run on the same commit.
2. If you have multiple commits with the same message. You can see this is the case in your screenshot. The commit ID sha's are different, but the commit message is the same.

Comment: The commits have different messsage
    The pipeline is not being run on the same commit as shown from SHA of the pipeline
    The issue is basically always the MR title is being used as pipeline name.
Thats the whole issue here